# Choose photo in UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c

I would like to choose existing photo, but also have option of take video or take photo too; how do I do that? I tried the below code. Notice that I did enable the source type photo library, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto {
  UIImagePickerController *uiipc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
  uiipc.delegate=self;
  uiipc.mediaTypes=@[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
  uiipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera|UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  uiipc.allowsEditing=YES;
  [self presentViewController:uiipc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pick one `sourceType`. You have to put up your own menu and then set it accordingly.

Comment: That seems like a very inconvenient thing.